# Is it possible to use Java, SWIG and Rust together?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, rust, swig, rust-cargo

I am trying to call into a [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) library from [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html) and I really want to use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to generate the interface layer from a [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) header file that I write (I also want to allow regular C clients to call into my library, hence I think it makes sense to maintain one interface header).

I am doing this all on [Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows) using [Mingw](http://mingw.org/) and [Rust (GNU ABI)](https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/rust-1.10.0-i686-pc-windows-gnu.msi).

I will go into exactly what I did and the result below but essentially I am getting an [UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html) at the end.  There are a couple of things that I think may be wrong but I am not sure and I am not sure how (or if) I can fix them:

1. SWIG puts numbers in the function name (you can see this if you edit the `testlib_wrap.c` file it produces in my example).
2. The JNI [documentation](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) says I need to pass the argument `-Wl,--add-stdcall-alias` when compiling but as I am building with cargo I am not sure how to do that (can I pass it if I build with rustc directly perhaps?  I could not see anything in the [man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/rustc))

So in a nutshell, my question is:

**How do you call into Rust from Java using SWIG**?

But I feel like I am scratching the surface of a solution so the answer may be resolving one or both of the points above so here is exactly where I am so far...

---

I start by making a new Rust library using [Cargo](https://crates.io/):

```
cargo new testlib
cd testlib
```

Create `testlib.h` with the contents:

```
void tell_me_the_answer(void);
```

Create a swig input file (`testlib.i`) with the following contents:

```
%module testlib
%{
#include "testlib.h"
%}
%include "testlib.h"
```

Run swig to generate some Java and C:

```
mkdir testlib
swig -outdir testlib -java -package testlib testlib.i
```

Create a main java class (`Program.java`) with the contents:

```
public final class Program {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("testlib"); 
    }
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        testlib.testlib.tell_me_the_answer();
    }
}
```

Compile the java:

```
javac Program.java testlib\testlib.java testlib\testlibJNI.java
```

Edit the `src\lib.rs` file that cargo made to implement the function:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn tell_me_the_answer() {
    println!("The answer is...APPLES!");
}
```

Create a new `build.rs` file to hook in compiling the swig output via the [gcc-rs](https://github.com/alexcrichton/gcc-rs) library, which contains:

```
extern crate gcc;
fn main() {
    gcc::Config::new()
                .file("testlib_wrap.c")
                .include("C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/include")
                .include("C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/include/win32")
                .compile("libtestlib.a");
}
```

Edit the `Cargo.toml` file so that it contains:

```
[package]
name = "testlib"
version = "0.1.0"
build = "build.rs"
[lib]
name = "testlib"
crate-type = ["dylib"]
[build-dependencies]
gcc = "0.3"
```

Compile the rust project:

```
cargo build
```

Run the java application:

```
java -Djava.library.path=target\debug Program
```

Get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: testlib.testlibJNI.tell_me_the_answer()V
    at testlib.testlibJNI.tell_me_the_answer(Native Method)
    at testlib.testlib.tell_me_the_answer(testlib.java:13)
    at Program.main(Program.java:6)
```

I had a look at the DLL that cargo made me in [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and it looks kind of empty (in terms of it's exports) and the single function looks a bit weird, to me at least, due to the **1**s in the name and the **@** part which I think the `--add-stdcall-alias` would remove right?

[image: Dependency Walker Output]

Am I close and the name in the DLL as shown in dependency walker is the root of my problem?
If it were `Java_testlib_testlibJNI_tell_me_the_answer` would it work?
If so, how do I make it so (I edited the `_wrap.c` file SWIG produced to remove the 1s but I am not sure how I will get rid of the @)?
If not, what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution, but it is not really beautiful so if anyone can make this seamless from cargo that would be a much nicer solution but a batch file will do for me for the time being.  Here is what I did...

I gave up on calling gcc from cargo, built a static lib from rust and then ran gcc from the command line to munge the rust generated staticlib in with the SWIG generated code and create a dynamic library like so...

I changed `Cargo.toml` to:

```
[package]
name = "testlib"
version = "0.1.0"
[lib]
name = "testlib"
crate-type = ["staticlib"]
```

Deleted `build.rs`

Built the static lib:

```
cargo build
```

Compiled the SWIG output and linked it with what cargo just produced like this:

```
gcc -shared -o target\debug\testlib.dll "-LC:/Program Files (x86)/Rust stable GNU 1.9/lib/rustlib/i686-pc-windows-gnu/lib" -Ltarget\debug "-IC:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/include" "-IC:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/include/win32" testlib_wrap.c -ltestlib -lws2_32 -luserenv -lgcc_eh -lshell32 -ladvapi32 -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias
```

Now I have a `testlib.dll` that looks fine in Dependency Walker and when I run it I see:

```
The answer is...APPLES!
```

Which is totally the right answer.